# PHP REGEX match a domain name from a given Url

Tags: php, regex

What i want is given domain is present in string or not.

examples are of my problem are

```
+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| input                                        | output                |
+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| http://www.example.com/questions/ask         | match or true         |
| http://example.com/check                     | match or true         |
| http://www.google.com/ig/moduleurl           |
|    =http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fquestion  | false                 |
| http://example.com/search/%25C3%25A9t%25     | match true            |
+----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

any help will be appreciable

Thanks

Comment: why  do you need a regex? wouldn't the php equivalent of `instr`/`index` suffice ?

Comment: dirty way: search `"/[\w.]*example.com/"`?

Comment: @Kent: the difficulty in url matching is to distinguish between `authority` and `query` portions (using the [rfc 3986 nomenclature](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3)). the query part may contain urls itself (think of redirection targets) which haven't  always been url-encoded properly. it gets really nasty if you encounter urls in the query part which have another url in _their_ query part and so on.

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regex here IMO:

using `parse_url()` [check man here](http://www.php.net/parse_url), you can get the domain, host... all you want, really. Coupled with the (extremely fast) string functions:

```
if (strstr(parse_url($input,PHP_URL_HOST),'example.com'))
{
    echo $input.' is a match';
}
```

But the quickest way in your scenario would be:

```
$match = strpos($input, 'example.com');
$match = $match !== false && $match <= 12 ? true : false;
//12 is max for https://www.example.com
```

You wouldn't even need the `!!(...);`, but that's just so you can se that `$match` is being assigned a boolean

But the first suggestion still looks cleaner and more readable, to my eye.

If a string beginning with the host you're looking for isn't valid either:

```
$match = strpos($input, 'example.com');
$match = !!($match && $match < 13);
```

Is the fastest approach I can think of

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~^(?:ht|f)tps?://[^/]*?(?<=\.|/)'.preg_quote($domain).'(?=/|$)~i';
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [**parse_url function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) rather than parsing whole URL:

```
$arr = parse_url($url);
$host = $arr['host'];

// now just match the hostname
if (preg_match('#^(?:[^.]+\.)*example\.com$#i', $host, $arr))
    var_dump($arr); // or return true;
```

This regex may also work:

```
if (preg_match('#^https?://(?:[^.]+\.)*example\.com/#i', $url, $arr))
   var_dump($arr); // return true;
```

Comment: this will match the presence of the relevant url inside the query string. use at least `#^https?://(?:[^.]+\.)*example\.com/#i` (caret mark start of test string)

Comment: @collapsar: Thanks, corrected, also added a parse_url based solution.